# Best practices for id in Watson Discovery Services

Tags: watson, watson-discovery

I've got a question around best practices with the document id's in Watson Discovery.  I've got a unique key in my data, and I'm wondering if I should pass that in as the id or let Discovery generate one.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

According to me, it is not possible to pass your own id (be its environment id, collection id, configuration id or document id) to Discovery service yet.

Every time, you create an environment or collection etc, Discovery itself generates a unique ID for it.

***Note***: Having manual intervention in generating IDs as well may lead to multiple confusions among the users as well.